# Why is Mockito.when Calling real method implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

I am trying to mock a method Using Mockito but it seems not to be working

```
private SpringContext springContext;

public Person(Directory Directory) {
    this.directory = directory;
    this.springContext = new SpringContextImpl();
}

public Message<?> receive(Message<?> result, Object source) {
     A bean = springContext.getBean(A.class);
}
```

```
@Configuration
public class SpringContextImpl implements ApplicationContextAware, SpringContext {
    private  ApplicationContext context;

     public <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }
}
```

I tried to mock **springContext.getBean** but it seems to be calling the real method and throwing a NullPointerException. I do not want it to call the real method.

```
@Mock
A a;

@BeforeEach
void init() {
    directory = mockDirectory();
    person = (new Person(directory));
}

void shouldTestMethod() {
    when(context.getBean(A.class)).thenReturn(a);
}
```

I tried using

```
doReturn(a).when(context).getBean(A.class);
```

but it still did not work. Please can someone help.

Answer (score 0):

We can only add stubbing to the mock objects, in other words you have to create mock for `SpringContext` and then add stubbing to it.

```
@Mock
private A a;

@Mock
private SpringContext springContext;

  @BeforeEach
  void init() {
  directory = mockDirectory();
  person = (new Person(directory));

  //then set the mock springContext to person using spring ReflectionTestUtils
  ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classNotify, "springContext", springContext);
 }

  void shouldTestMethod() {
  when(context.getBean(A.class)).thenReturn(a);
 }
```

While working on spring boot i will highly recommend writing integration test cases using [@SpringBootTest](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing#integration-testing-with-springboottest) annotation and looking into dependency injection using `@Autowire`

Comment: I'm still getting the error after adding @SpringContext 
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(p, "springContext", springContext);
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(p, "directory", mockDirectory());

Comment: can u show error @Chunks

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at c.p.f.config.SpringContextImpl.getBean(SpringContextImpl.java:22)
 at c.p.f.i.Person.receive(PollMessageAdvice.java:61)
 at c.p.f.i.PersonTest.shouldTest(PersonTest.java:105)

Comment: can u add the complete test class code @Chunks

Answer (score 0):

generally, it's better not to have mocks that return other mocks. In this case, you can use `@SpringBootTest` where you start the Spring context and replace

```
@Mock // we will change this
private A a;

// ReflectionTestUtils.setField(classNotify, "springContext", springContext); 
// -> and we'll remove this

void shouldTestMethod() {
   when(context.getBean(A.class)).thenReturn(a); //and remove this
   // then test something ...
}
```

And use `@MockBean` instead:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyintegrationTest {

    @MockBean
    private A a;

    void shouldTestMethod() {
        // test something ...
    }
}
```

read more about this here: https://www.baeldung.com/java-spring-mockito-mock-mockbean#spring-boots-mockbean-annotation

Comment: I'm still getting the error after adding @SpringContext ReflectionTestUtils.setField(p, "springContext", springContext); ReflectionTestUtils.setField(p, "directory", mockDirectory());

Comment: with `@SpringBootTest` at a class level and `@MockBean` you won't need anything else.  So we will remove the `ReflectionUtils` thing. I am updating the answer now

Comment: It's not working. notice that Person class is not a Component. it's more like a DTO so that's why i am initializing it with new Person (directory)

Comment: you have to keep creatin it manually. unfortunately in your question is not enough code to understand what you're trying to test.